# Need a way to select then go to specified div based on selection

Tags: html

here is what I have put together so far but it seems my hidden fields are not toggling when the yes or no is selected.  Yes in the field - Do you have empowerment should bring up an input field asking for Employee #, while No should bring up a a field asking for Operator number.

The system we use at work will only run html 4, no javascript or php.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><span style="white-space: nowrap;" nowrap="nowrap"><label>Is this over $10?</label></span></td>
<td><select id="overTenToggle" name="overTenToggle" class="required" data-hidediv="overTen" onchange="changeHiddenView(this)">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="hide">No</option>
  <option value="show">Yes</option>
 </select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="overTen" style="display:none">
<table>
<tr>
<td><span style="white-space: nowrap;" nowrap="nowrap"><label>Do you have empowerment?</label></span></td>
<td><select id="empowermentToggle" name="empowermentToggle" onchange="changeMultiHide(this)" >
  <option value="" ></option>
  <option value="empowermentEmp" data-multihide="[{target:'empowermentOp',action:'hide'}, {target:'empowermentEmp',action:'show'}]" >No</option>
  <option value="empowermentOp" data-multihide="[{target:'empowermentOp',action:'show'}, {target:'empowermentEmp',action:'hide'}]" >Yes</option>
 </select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="empowermentOp" style="display:none">
<table>
<tr>
 <td><label>Empowerment Employee Op Number:</label></td>
 <td colspan="6"><input class="numeric amount" name="opNum" id="opNum" size="15"></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="empowermentEmp" style="display:none">
<table>
<tr>
 <td><label>Leadership Op Number:</label></td>
 <td colspan="6"><input class="numeric amount" name="empNum" id="empNum" size="15"></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You might want to rephrase it and include some code if you have

Comment: It must allow JavaScript or those `onchange` event handlers are not going to do much...